# GCP KMS createKey function never resolve

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I am using NodeJS v10 (AngularJS MeanStack) with GCP KMS (@google-cloud/kms) to create key, encrypt & decrypt strings using those keys.

I am in a very strange issue, where createKeys function doesn't return to its callback (but timeout after a very long interval). there is not error or result coming into that function.
While using the same manually created keys, I can encrypt & decrypt with the same SDK.

my createKeys function looks like

```
function createKeyHSM(keyId, done) {
if (!keyId) {
    return done('Google KMS - Cannot create Key - KeyID is missing', null);
}
const keyRingName = client.keyRingPath(projectId, locationId, keyRingId);
client.createCryptoKey({
    parent: keyRingName,
    cryptoKeyId: 'my-test',
    cryptoKey: {
        purpose: 'ENCRYPT_DECRYPT',
        versionTemplate: {
            algorithm: 'GOOGLE_SYMMETRIC_ENCRYPTION',
            protectionLevel: 'HSM',
        },
        // Rotate the key every 90 days.
        rotationPeriod: config.googleKMS.rotationPeriod,
        nextRotationTime: {
            seconds: new Date().getTime() / 1000 + 60 * 60 * 72,
        },
    },
}).then(result => {
    return done(null, result);
}).catch(err => {
    ccmLogger.error(new VError(err));
    return done(err);
});
}
```

The strange part is, if I create the same key using the console and try to encrypt or decrypt, it works like charm.
here is the encrypt code for reference:

```
function encryptSymmetric(dataToEncrypt, keyName, done) {
if ((!dataToEncrypt) || (!keyName)) {
    return done('Google KMS - Cannot encrypt, missing plainText or KeyID.', null);
}
const keyPath = client.keyRingPath(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, keyName);
client.encrypt({
    name: keyPath,
    plaintext: Buffer.from(dataToEncrypt),
}, null, (err, encryptResponse) => {
    if(err) {
        done(err);
    }
    const ciphertext = encryptResponse.ciphertext.toString('base64');
    done(null, ciphertext);
});
}
```

Based on the behavior above, I conclude that there isn't any connectivity issue.

**While the funny part is, if I run these code in an isolated new project, they do work but not on the current project and I cant seem to think of any reason of its behavior.**

Comment: Can you share more of your code and any console output? Can you try with async/await?

Comment: I am calling this function on a user click now. I tried with Async/wait, callback, native promises and it doesn't work. I was able to limit the error scope and it is behaving like this when i add rotationPeriod inside the createKey function. If i remove the rotationPeriod config, it works fine.. But i wonder how is it working on an isolated project?
Now if i try to add a rotationPeriod after key creation it gives me an error of UpdateKey permission (which i can fix), but it is able to create a key with rortationPeriod in one project and not on the other.